# In slave Mongodb 3.0.1, when I run "show dbs" command I'm getting the below error

Tags: mongodb

After clustering the Mongodb 3.0.1 in two machines. In slave mode when I run this command **"show dbs"** it is showing **"not master"** error.

Here is the error:

```
E QUERY Error: listDatabases failed: 
        { "note" : "from execCommand", "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "not master" }
at Error (<anonymous>)
```

Please tell me, how can I overcome this problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please use `rs.slaveOk()` on the mongo console you are getting the error.

Comment: be aware that this command is case sensitive, you should type: rs.slaveOk()